# Solve the differential equation with variable separable method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am not able to figure out how to integrate after separating

---

Equation is:
$$y\sqrt{1-x^2}dy+x\sqrt{1-y^2}dx=0$$

In my book there is no solution but have answer:
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=c$$

Comment: For evaluation of $\int\frac u{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$, keep $1-u^2=m$.

Comment: Use separation of variables method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y\sqrt{1-x^2}dy+x\sqrt{1-y^2}dx=0$$
$$-2y\sqrt{1-x^2}dy-2x\sqrt{1-y^2}dx=0$$
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}d(1-y^2)+\sqrt{1-y^2}d(1-x^2)=0$$
Substitute $u=1-x^2 \,\,, v=1-y^2$:
$$\sqrt{u}dv+\sqrt v du=0$$
$$\dfrac {dv} {\sqrt{v}}+\dfrac {du} {\sqrt u}=0$$
Integrate.
$$ {\sqrt{v}}+ {\sqrt u}=C$$
$$ {\sqrt{1-y^2}}+ \sqrt {1-x^2}=C$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\int \frac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}dv=-\sqrt{1-v^2}+c_1$ which can be obtained by the substitution $u=1-v^2$ for example.

Then separating the differential equation we have $$y\sqrt{1-x^2}dy+x\sqrt{1-y^2}dx=0$$
$$y\sqrt{1-x^2}dy=-x\sqrt{1-y^2}dx$$
$$\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

and integrating gives $$-\sqrt{1-y^2}+c=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ or $$\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-y^2}=c$$